# WebJobs - How to configure TimeTrigger RunOnStartup in appsettings?

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, timer-trigger

The documentation is very clear - **set RunOnStartup = false in production**. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example)

However, how do we do that without 'remembering' to change true to false in the code?

I can't see how to pass a config setting from appsettings.json like you can for the Cron String?

e.g.

```
public async Task DataRetentionAllTenantsAndAccounts([TimerTrigger("%App:DataRetentionAllTenantsAndAccountsCronTrigger%", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started DataRetentionAllTenantsAndAccounts");
        log.LogInformation("Started DataRetentionAllTenantsAndAccounts");
        await _mailMiloManager.DataRetentionAllTenantsAndAccountsAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Functions RunOnStartUp set in configuration rather than at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719828/azure-functions-runonstartup-set-in-configuration-rather-than-at-compile-time)

Comment: [Parametrize runOnStartup in function.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205429/parametrize-runonstartup-in-function-json) and [Azure Function timer configure through app settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538960/azure-function-timer-configure-through-app-settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here is the code to set `RunOnStartup = True` in production environment.*

```cs
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("%TimerInterval%" 

#if DEBUG 
,RunOnStartup=true // When debugging... run the job as soon as we press debug, no need to wait for the timer. 
#endif

    )]TimerInfo myTimer)

    {
```

*This you can do it using Visual Code. check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63855478/15969833) for complete information.*